# Python numpy library log method returning wrong value

Tags: python, numpy

Python numpy library log method returning wrong value so please help me.

```
import numpy as np
print('Log :',np.log(0.25))
```

numpy log method returns `-1.38629436112`

Excel log function `=LOG(0.25)` returns `-0.602059991327962`
Then I Calculated manually using calculator it returns `-0.602059991327962`.

Comment: It is returning the base e log rather than the base 10 one.

Comment: You are confused with `log_2`, `log_e` and `log_10`

Answer (score 5):

Because the `log` function is in base `e` while your calculator and excel are base `10` by default. Use `np.log10(0.25)` and you'll get the value you want.